# A question of the volume of high-dimensional unit balls concentrated near its equator

Tags: geometry

I have known that as the dimension $d$ increases, the volume of $d$-dimensional unit ball concentrated near its equator.

But in a ball, there are numerous different equators. Then does it mean that the volume lies in the overlap of these equators?

Comment: where did you get such an information ?

Comment: Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210291/how-to-explain-the-concentration-of-measure-phenomenon-intuitively

Comment: @GCab https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/CStheory-infoage/chap1-high-dim-space.pdf   1.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume of a $d$-dimensional ball is distributed uniformly throughout the $d$-ball.

There isn't any special "magnetism" of an equator drawing the volume toward it.
It's merely the case that by making a complete circuit around an equator, you will pass close to a relatively large portion of the interior of the $d$-ball.
The more dimensions, the higher a proportion of the interior you pass close by.

You do not enhance this effect by intersecting equators. Try it on a three-dimensional ball: unless you are merely intersecting the first equator with itself, the intersection consists of two points which are the poles of a third equator,
and therefore the volume of the ball is relatively *far* from the intersection of the equators.

In general, by intersecting $d$ equators of a $d$-ball, you can easily make it so that the intersection is empty and is not near to *any* of the volume of the $d$-ball.
I believe the only way to avoid an empty intersection in that case is if you arrange some of the equators so that they are redundant (that is, you get the same intersection in the end even if you leave those equators out of the list to be intersected).

Answer (score 0):

Reading the paper, actually the use of the word "equator" is a bit misleading at the beginning.

But at pag. 9, 10 it is made clear that, considering a section at $x_1 = const$, they call equator the plane through the center $x_1 = 0$. Then by "concentrated at the equator" it is meant that the area of section at $x_1= const$ , a d-1 ball, is increasing very fast from $x_1=1$ (the Pole) down to $x_1=0$, just because of $r$ raised to a high exponent.